# Using CASE for DATETIME data Studio

Tags: case, looker-studio

What `CASE` do I use for `DATETIME`?
How should the formula for choosing dates in the Google Data Studio date look like?

```
CASE
  WHEN order_date = "20211020" THEN "New"
  ELSE "Old"
END
```

I have error:

> Invalid formula - Operator "=" doesn't support DATETIME = TEXT. Operator "=" supports ANY = ANY.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The message itself already indicates the problem. If order_date is a field of type date, it is not possible to compare with an element of another type, in this case with an element of type text "20211020" (quotes indicate that it is text). If your date is being received by DataStudio as text, I recommend formatting it to the Date type using the formula PARSE_DATE().

One solution to create date ranges for sorting: use DATE_DIFF. For example,

```
CASE 
   WHEN DATE_DIFF( TODAY(), order_date) <= 10 THEN "new"
   WHEN DATE_DIFF( TODAY(), order_date) > 10 THEN "old"
END
```